# Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil: NilClass in Flutter Application

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on the Flutter application which is based on a simple Chat. I am using **Firebase Auth**, **Firebase Messaging**, **Google Sign in**, and **Cloud Firestore**. Everything is working smoothly in Android but when I run this application in an iOS environment, I am facing some issues like,

**" Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil: NilClass
Exception: Error running pod install "**

I have also installed a cocoapod but it was not working properly, that time I also face another issue which is mention below:-

**" Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil: NilClass "**

I had also used some solution which is a reference on Github but still, those thing is not working.
============== References:-

1. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8425
2. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75961

================ This is my **Flutter Doctor** response:-

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.0.1 20B50 darwin-x64, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

=================== This is my **pubspec.yaml**:-

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  **google_sign_in: 4.4.3**

  **firebase_auth: 0.15.4**

  **cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5**

  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3

  **firebase_messaging: 6.0.13**

  flutter_local_notifications:

  http: ^0.12.2
```

==================== This is my **cocoapods enviornment** and also **pod file**

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.10.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
    RubyGems : 3.1.4
        Host : macOS 11.0.1 (20B50)
       Xcode : 12.2 (12B45b)
         Git : git version 2.23.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Installation Source

```
Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

In this podfile, I have removed pods because of occurring some issues which I mentioned above.

I am working with the **macOS Big Sur version - 11.0.1** for development in **Android Studio version 4.1** and Testing that application in **iPad(6th generation) version 14.2**.

Can anyone please assist me with what I am doing wrong? so further I can able to resolve this error in iOS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this out, see if anything in the thread works for you. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8425

Comment: Ok, so, according to the first link you sent, [this issue is an issue with the error inspector in CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8425#issuecomment-455291910). This means that we would first have to review that your CocoaPods setup is correct, which means that, if possible, could you edit your post to include your file structure so that we may see what files (such as .ruby-version and .xcodeproj) you have, which you might be missing and which might require reconfiguring? We kinda need to figure out what's the issue with CocoaPods before we can find the issue in code

Comment: @NisanthReddy - Thank you for responding to my request. As you mentioned earlier this (github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8425) link I tried with that solution but still, I am not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: @fabc - Thank you for responding to my post. Hence I am working with flutter till now I am using default project files created by flutter when we began to start the development. I am not doing anything specific in Xcode for iOS. Still, if you want to show the files I can represent to you those files that are created by flutter for iOS by default.

Comment: Please do, I know it might seem silly, but sometimes even the defaults or certain automated systems can cause errors.

Comment: @fabc - Hello, below you can find the files which are created by Flutter in Xcode. Let me know if you have any problems while opening it. Link:- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LRjBMyVtQGD_6Hb7Jc6Kr9vmdHjZpML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see that the comment section is getting bigger, I'll follow up here.

I see in the drive [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LRjBMyVtQGD_6Hb7Jc6Kr9vmdHjZpML5) that there is some problems with the `.xcodeproj` file, could you attach it too to the drive?
In some cases the default pods installation is wrong and it needs to manually edit the `.xcodeproj` file to remove the sections causing the problem.

In some cases, after running `gem update xcodeproj` solves the issue.

In addition, it would be nice if you use the latest CocoaPod version, as maybe there is some compatibility issues between Xcode version and CocoaPod version.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for responding! Below you can check the link for **.xcodeproj**. Let me know you have any trouble while opening it. [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bmz7Hd085OcX1PhJ0CbwA3phyVOqZ_zV?usp=sharing).

Comment: I don't find the **.xcodeproj** file in the link. Btw, have you tried updating CocoaPods to the latest version and running the command I suggested above?